# Series convergence radius proximity

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x-4)^n $ converges in x=1 and diverges in x=9.
I can say that the convergence radius (R) is at least 3 and at most 5, thus 3<R<5. Is there a way I can tell it even more accurate?

Comment: That series *diverges* when $x=1$.

Comment: it should have been R

Comment: What has that to do with my comment? You claimed that your series converges when $x=1$, and I told you it does not.

Comment: aha, sorry, so what is then the radius?

Comment: Please meaningful set a title.

Comment: The radius of convergence is $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you have some confusion.
Given series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (x-4)^n$.we know that this power series will converge for $x=4$(why!).

Now I am going to use ratio test you can also use root test.
\begin{equation}
|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|\frac{(x-4)^{n+1}}{(x-4)}|=|(x-4)|=L(say).
\end{equation}
Then series will converge if $L<1$. If $L=1$ then you cannot decide. If $L>1$ then series will diverge.

If $L<1$, then:
$|x-4|<1 \Rightarrow 3<x<5$.

If $L=1$, then:
$|x-4|=1 \Rightarrow x=3,5$. If $x=3$ then the series surely divergent also if $x=5$(By **necessary condition of convergence of a series**).
\begin{equation}
ROC= \frac{upper ~value-lower ~value}{2}=\frac{5-3}{2}=1.
\end{equation}

Comment: thank you very much :) now it is clear to me

Comment: @Rikib16 you're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

It is well-known that the geometric series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_0r^n$$ converges to $$\frac{a_0}{1-r}$$ iff $$|r|<1$$ and that means that the radius of convergence is one.

Comment: thanks a lot! :)